# Swiping view to different view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, swipe

I'm trying to accomplish the following effect:
[image: swiping]

I want a view to be swipable. During and after being swiped, another view should appear below it (which I can specify). I tried using a [RecyclerView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) together with [ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/helper/ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback.html) following [this tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html), but this only allows specifying a `RecyclerView.ViewHolder` at the start and then update it using an updated dataset. What I want is to completely specify a new `RecyclerView.ViewHolder` for the view below when an [onSwiped](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/helper/ItemTouchHelper.Callback.html#onSwiped(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.ViewHolder,%20int)) method is called.

I'd be grateful if you could point me to either a better way to use `RecyclerView` or another way to accomplish this task.

My code looks as follows.

MyActivity class:

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_swipe_test);

        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);

        // use this setting to improve performance if you know that changes
        // in content do not change the layout size of the RecyclerView
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        // use a linear layout manager
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

        // specify an adapter (see also next example) -- useless at the moment
        String[] myDataset = {"a"};
        mAdapter = new MyAdapter(myDataset);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback simpleItemTouchCallback = new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT) {
            /*
            No need to worry about this since we're not supporting drag and drop.
             */
            @Override
            public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int swipeDir) {
                //Remove swiped item from list and notify the RecyclerView
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };

        ItemTouchHelper itemTouchHelper = new ItemTouchHelper(simpleItemTouchCallback);
        itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(mRecyclerView);
    }
}
```

MyAdapter class:

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ChallengeAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
    // useless at the moment since we are only using one item
    private String[] mDataset;

    // Provide a reference to the views for each data item
    // Complex data items may need more than one view per item, and
    // you provide access to all the views for a data item in a view holder
    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        // each data item is just a string in this case
        public RelativeLayout mRvItem;
        public MyViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            mRvItem = (RelativeLayout) v;
        }
    }

    // Provide a suitable constructor (depends on the kind of dataset)
    public ChallengeAdapter(String[] myDataset) {
        // useless at the moment
        mDataset = myDataset;
    }

    // Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        // create a new view
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.rv_item, parent, false);
        MyViewHolder vh = new MyViewHolder(v);
        return vh;

    }

    // Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        // - get element from your dataset at this position
        // - replace the contents of the view with that element
    }

    // Return the size of your dataset (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        // useless at the moment
        return mDataset.length;
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: @AnjaliTripathi Posted code.

Answer (score 0):

Use this library to accomplish feature what you wanted 
[Bayoz Swipe Menu](http://www.anjadev.com/all/programming/android_development/swipe-menu-for-list-view-swipemenulistview/)

Answer (score 0):

This library looks good. Posted on androidweekly this week.
https://github.com/TUBB/SwipeMenuRecyclerView

Comment: This only allows 2 views: content and menu. This is useful in certain scenarios, but I think is not applicable in this case.